# grunt no target found issue

Tags: gruntjs

I have written a following file grunt.js

```
var _path = require('path');

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var config = {
    };


    function addProject(project) {
        grunt.helper('addProject', config, project);
    }

    addProject({
        name:'mytest',
        type:'module',
        sourcePath:'../source',
        outputPath:'../test/',
        version : grunt.option('ver')||'0.1.0.0'
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'module closureCompiler');
    grunt.initConfig(config);
};
```

when i run it using a command in my bat file  module closureCompiler sync, it gives an error saying

```
Running "sync" task
>> No "sync" targets found.
<WARN> Task "sync" failed. Use --force
```

What does this mean?

Comment: What parameters are you passing it exactly? You haven't configured the sync task.

Comment: ok tell me howaand where i should configure the sync task ?

Comment: https://github.com/tomusdrw/grunt-sync/blob/master/readme.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message points out you need to define a target for the `sync` task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    sync: {
        target: {}   // <= needs to be defined
    }
});
```